# Intuitive/Visual solution for: There are $k$ balls in a bowl. How many draws does it on average take, to get one specific ball?

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following problem:

There are $k$ balls in a bowl. So $k$ different possibilities of the same probability $\frac{1}{k}$ to be drawn from the bowl. Any drawn ball is immediately replaced into the bowl again. How many draws does it on average take, to get one specific ball?

With $k=2$ it would be like a coin toss. With $k=6$ like rolling a dice.

So, you see, it's not really an advanced problem. However, I'm looking for the most intuitive/visual solution.

Comment: how do you compute it for a dice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A most intuitive is perhaps referring to the law of large numbers.

Denote by $X$ the geometric variable in question, i.e. the number of draws before we draw the specific ball B. Now let us draw the balls indefinitely and count how may times we take B. The number $N_n$ of draws before we take it $n$ times is the sum of independent copies of $X$. Therefore, by the law of large numbers, 
$$
\frac{N_n}{n}\to \mathbb{E}[X], n\to\infty.
$$
On the other hand, $\frac{n}{N_n}$ is the ratio of draws of B to the total draws. Again, by the law of large numbers,
$$
\frac{n}{N_n}\to \frac1k, n\to\infty.
$$
Hence we get $\mathbb{E}[X] = k$.

Answer (score 9):

Let $E$ denote the result.

Consider the first trial.  You win with probability $\frac 1k$.  With probability $\frac {k-1}k$ you start over.  It follows that $$E=\frac 1k\times 1 +\frac {k-1}k\times \left(E+1\right)\implies E=k$$

Comment: What if $E = \infty$?

Comment: @zhoraster  fairly easy to see that that is not the case.  For a bernoulli process with probability $p$, the probability that it takes $n$ trials before a success is  $(1-p)^np$ and $\sum np(1-p)^n$ clearly converges.

Comment: Series, not fair. Let us draw balls not more than $N$ times, and $E_N$ be the corresponding expectation. Then $E_N = \frac1k + (1-\frac1k) (E_{N-1}+1)\le \frac1k + (1-\frac1k) (E_{N}+1)$, whence $E_N\le k$. Then we get the finiteness as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: @integralette   This of the first try.   If you win (prob $\frac 1k$) you are done in one step.  This is the first  term on the right hand of my equation.  If you lose (prob. $\frac {k-1}k$), you are right back to where you started...so your expectation is $E$ again, but you have already tried once, so taking that path is expected to take $E+1$ tries.  That gives you the second term.

Comment: You can always split up expectation this way.  If I tell you there is a $\frac 13$ chance your coin is fair (so you expect it to take $2$ tries to get $H$) and a $\frac 23$ chance your coin is weighted (in which case you expect it to take, say, $5$ tries to get $H$, then your total expectation is $\frac 13\times 2 +\frac 23\times 5$.

Comment: This kind of recursive argument comes up all the time.  I agree it isn't intuitive at first, but it is worth getting used to.

Comment: @integralette I'm ok with leaving my answer as it stands, stark though it may be.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Please feel free to post your own solution.  People often post solutions which elaborate on details omitted in other posts.

Comment: No harm done, but I don't care to discuss the matter further.  I think as a general rule, you ought to ask people before proposing substantial edits to their posts, but of course, I don't speak for anyone besides myself.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the expected number of draws, if assuming you only draw repeatedly until you get the right ball.

This is given by:
$$
E[\#\text{draws}]=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i P(i)
$$

With $P(i)$ the probability of taking $i$ draws. Computing for some cases:

$$
P(1) = 1/k
$$
$$
P(2) = ((k-1)/k)(1/k)
$$

$$
P(3) = ((k-1)/k)^2(1/k)
$$
...

$$
P(i) = ((k-1)/k)^{(i-1)}(1/k)
$$

Thus:

$$
E[\#\text{draws}]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty i ((k-1)/k)^{(i-1)}(1/k)=(1/k)\sum_{i=1}^\infty i ((k-1)/k)^{(i-1)}
$$

Which is an [Arithmetic-Geometric sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence). The partial sum of such sequence is given by:

$$
S_n =\frac{a-[a+(n-1)d]r^n}{1-r}+\frac{dr(1-r^{n-1})}{(1-r)^2}
$$

Then for a ratio $r$ such that $|r|<1$, the series converges to:

$$
S =\frac{a}{1-r}+\frac{dr}{(1-r)^2}
$$

In the current case:

- $r= (k-1)/k$ so $(1-r)=1/k$
- $a=1$
- $d=1$

So the arithmetic geometric sum is given by:
$$
S =\frac{1}{(1/k)}+\frac{(k-1)/(k)}{(1/k)^2}=k+k(k-1)=k^2
$$

Going back to our previous summation:
$$
E[\#\text{draws}]=(1/k)\sum_{i=1}^\infty i ((k-1)/k)^{(i-1)}=(1/k)\left(k^2 \right)=k
$$